# Refresh UITableViewController data

Tags: ios, swift, api, uitableview

I have 2 controllers, **DashboardController** and **LocateVehicleController**. LocateVehicleController has **UITableViewController**.

In DashboardController, On button press I am doing API call and getting data. And sending array to LocateVehicleController.

```
 let locateVehicleStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let locateVehicleController = locateVehicleStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tempID") as? LocateVehicle
 self.present(locateVehicleController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
 locateVehicleController?.dataArray = self.locateVehicleDataArr
 locateVehicleController?.tableView.reloadData()
```

In LocateVehicleController I have refresh button, If I press refresh button I need to update the tableview controller data which I have used API call data from DashboardController.

As per my understanding when I press refresh button, same API call will invoke. Please help to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the issue you facing? "As per my understanding when I press refresh button, same API call will invoke" you already saved API data in array , just pass array to second controller and reload table accordingly.No need to call same API again in second controller.

Comment: @TusharSharma its again you, thank you for response. I have done every thing and showing data in uitableview. If i refresh button in second controller how it will update the array that is presented in firstview controller.

Comment: As you mentioned you have passed array from first view to second view, so now you have that array holding your data (dataArray), so just reload table on refresh button and use this array to populate.

Comment: i misunderstood the question i suppose, are you trying to populate table on second view with passed array, or do you want to update array with some new data on second view upon clicking refresh button, which is already presenting data on table?

Comment: I am showing tableview data which i have returned from dashboardcontroller.

Comment: You then need to call an API that updates your newly added values in actual API as well, and then fetch result from updated API, just updating array want to everything.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try

Answer (score 0):

I would move the logic of calling of this API to another class. Inject this class into `DashboardController` and `LocateVehicleController` and use it to fetch you data. Something like this:

```
struct Vehicle {
}

protocol VehicleDataFetcherProtocol {
    func getVehicleData(completionHandler:([Vehicle])->()) // assuming the data is in form of an Array of a class/struct Vehicle
}

class VehicleDataFetcher: VehicleDataFetcherProtocol {
    // Hit API, get data and call the completion  hanlder
    func getVehicleData(completionHandler:([Vehicle])->()) {

    }
}

class DashboardController:UIViewController {
    private var vehicleDataFetcher: VehicleDataFetcher!

    func injectVehicleDataFetcher(dataFetcher:VehicleDataFetcher) {
        self.vehicleDataFetcher = dataFetcher
    }

    func presentLocateVehicle() {
        let locateVehicleStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let locateVehicleController = locateVehicleStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tempID") as? LocateVehicleController
        self.present(locateVehicleController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        locateVehicleController?.injectVehicleDataFetcher(dataFetcher: self.vehicleDataFetcher)
        locateVehicleController?.dataArray = self.locateVehicleDataArr
        locateVehicleController?.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

class LocateVehicleController:UIViewController {
    private var vehicleDataFetcher: VehicleDataFetcher!

    func injectVehicleDataFetcher(dataFetcher:VehicleDataFetcher) {
        self.vehicleDataFetcher = dataFetcher
    }


}
```